# Get coordinates of point regardless of resolution

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, swift3

Can you give me a way to get coordinates of point which will be the same in all iOS devices?

I found in article [Coordinate Systems and Transforms](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Transforms/Transforms.html)

> The user coordinate space in Cocoa is the environment you use for all your drawing commands. It represents a fixed scale coordinate space, which means that the drawing commands you issue in this space result in graphics whose size is consistent regardless of the resolution of the underlying device.

I tried to do this like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    if let touch = touches.first{
        let lastPoint = touch.location(in: self.view.superview)
        let precisePoint = graphView.convert(lastPoint, to:    self.view.superview)
    }
}
```

But lastPoint and precisePoint depends on used device.

Thanks for help

Comment: Well, the lastpoint will be relative to self.views coordinates while your precisePoint will use lastPoint where it is relative to the graphView and convert that place to where it is relative to self.view so it is no wonder the points do not match up.  The only circumstance I see the two points being the same is if self.view and graphView were exactly the same size.  I suggest you rethink your point conversion.  Furthermore it would help to know what your intent is behind calculating the two points.

Comment: Have you tried dividing the points by the screen bounds? That should give you a relative point and then multiply that point by screen bounds everytime before displaying it.

Comment: @Calimari328 I know that this two points will be different. I just tried to use [link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicoordinatespace)

Comment: @Rikh of course you are right, simplest solution is always the better one. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Rikh answer below:

```
var points = [CGPoint]()

//MARK: Touch events
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>,
                           with event: UIEvent?){
    if let touch = touches.first{
        let lastPoint = touch.location(in: self.view.superview)

        let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds

        points.append(CGPoint(x: lastPoint.x / bounds.maxX, y: lastPoint.y / bounds.maxY))
    }
}


func convertPointsToView(){
    let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds

    for point in points{
        let convertedPoint = CGPoint(x: point.x * bounds.maxX, y: point.y * bounds.maxY)

        print(convertedPoint)
    }
}
```